# Doubly Linked List with separate left and right node but same tail

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search-tree, doubly-linked-list

I'm working on double linked list where the head has to possessing 2 "hands" , left and right, and both hands must end up at the same tail.
And in the end, it should be able to print the value of

- Head - Left - Tail
- Head - Right - Tail

Like Binary Searching but must end up at the same tail.

I'm a little bit confuse about what should I use for create left and right node.
I've tried using a lot of middle insertion methods, and after a week I still can't figure out how to get the print out I want.

I tried to use Binary Searching method too, reference  [HERE](https://ideone.com/AyJUSh), but can't figure out how to make this one tail that all the hands should end up to.

This is how I write my Struct

```
struct City
{
    char name[20], place[20], food[20];
    struct City *next;
}
*head, *tail, *new, *right,*left,*del_temp, *temp, *temp2;
```

I used this one too... but still not work out

```
struct City
{
    char name[20], place[20], food[20];
    struct City *right;
    struct City *left;
}
*head, *tail, *new, *del_temp, *temp, *temp2;
```

Sorry for lacking code, I made several project with each different insertion methods. I'm not sure which one to put here.

My question is, how should I go from here ?
Should I use tree and subtrees for left and right hand ? what the algorithm I should use ?

If I were to continue with double linked list, how do I get the separate output for both left and right hand? Or if I were to continue with binary searching, how do I get the exact one tail in the end ?

Any advice ?

Thanks before

Comment: left and right go to the same tail? are you talking about ring linked list?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Yes, some kind of ring linked list / circular linked list, but instead of going circular, I need to make separate output like I write above. If I were to reverse the node order, the head and tail will swap. And advice ?

Comment: i am very confused. doubly linked list has no left or right node but previous and next node. what you are talking about should be a binary tree, with leaves go to the same ending point. so isn't what you need to do, just assigning left and right to be tail as default, instead of null? you need to make your question clearer.

Comment: uh.... what? Isn't this more like a circular linked list? And isn't this just a diamond? What exactly are you asking here?... This certainly isn't a binary search tree because each node branches off into two; the way you have it described, left and right might as well be prev and next, and the only thing you need to do is to keep iterating until you find that the next pointers would be equal to each other or to one of the current pointers.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr I'm really sorry about that, I know it has no left and right node, I was just so confuse how to put it, left and right was just the name I give :)

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to use a circularly doubly linked list so it would go

```
                               Head
                         Left        Right
                               Tail
```

Link each one to the left and right of each other back and forth creating the double link and then what you can do is when you want to right the right side just start from the head, go to the right hand and then print and stop at the tail. Same would go for the left and if you need to start with the tail you can do that too since you have a unique pointer for it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCNzn.png

a badly drawn picture but with arrows!

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment, but is this the type of structure you want?

```
         .-> N1 <---> N2 <---> N3 <-.
Head <__/                            \ __> Tail
        \.-> N4 <---> N5 <---> N6 <-./
```

I'm not sure exactly what your requirements are.

Comment: ahaa, that's two lists sharing the same sentinels.

Comment: Ahh..yes, like this O.o

Comment: @SylvieYunjae: Soo, what exactly are you trying to do? What does this have to do with binary trees? Could you provide: (1) sample input, (2) expected output, and (3)  code that you wrote which is having problems with that input?